# Why clipping mask makes everything disappear?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

So I tried all the suggested solutions in similar topics, however, nothing works so far. I have a group of objects and I want to use a clipping mask. My object is on the top, but no matter if it's transparent or not this happens:[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's simply not enough information in this question for it to be answered.  What does your mask path look like? What does the content you are trying to mask look like? If you are attempting to create a clipping mask of that entire blazer in your image, it won't work because a clipping mask path has to be **one** path, not a collection of paths.